# Get 10 or less days before a given date

Tags: mysql

i'm try to get <= 10days before a given date, but all i've tried did not work. i even tried removing the <= so that it will just be 10 days, but still to no avail. It showed me all the table even when the due_date is 40days. but all i wanted is a day not greater than 10 days but 10days or lesser

this is what i did:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DATE_SUB(due_date, INTERVAL 10 DAY)

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DATE_SUB(due_date, - INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

both didn't what could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You see how "<=" appears in your question? Well, it's missing in your answer.

Comment: I think it is very unclear what you want. Can you show sample data, expected result or something like that?